# Intense and intensive about drinking?

Tags: word-choice, difference, expressions, idiomatic-language

"He's on the fifth drink or something since we got here. It looks pretty intense/intensive. Maybe we should go talk to him."

Could both "intense" and "intensive" be used here naturally? Do they differ in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Either word could be used, but neither word seems natural to me in that context. Of the two, "intensive" is the less common, and less natural of the two.
Are you saying that the man, who is likely drunk by now, is "intense"? Or are you describing the situation? If the latter, the word "serious" would fit better.

Comment: I'm describing them seeing him alone at the bar, drinking hard, not focused on anything else but his drink.

Comment: Jack, you can ask questions in comments before giving a proper answer. A good answer doesn't have a question back to the OP in it

Answer (score 0):

Only "intense" is correct. "Intensive" has specific meanings, and describing a situation is not one of them.

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intensive)

1. ***intensive**: of, relating to, or marked by intensity or intensification, such as:*

   **a:** highly concentrated `intensive study`

   **b:** tending to strengthen or increase, especially : tending to give force
   or emphasis `intensive adverb`

   **c:** constituting or relating to a
   method designed to increase productivity by the expenditure of more
   capital and labor rather than by increase in scope `intensive farming`